# Can not Like on production server

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have integrated the Facebook-Like-Button on my Page. When I test this local on my machine with a valid url, so it works fine. But when i do my Website on my web server so it doesn't work. For my productive website I have another URL and another Facebook-App-ID.

When I would "like" on my productive website, it checks the button and than it jump back to zero likes. I don't know why :(

I have tested another URL and another Application on Facebook, but the same issue.

Any idea what is wrong?

I have integrated the button like this:

```
<fb:like href="#local.review.likelink#" send="false" layout="button_count" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

or make sure to define a valid URL.

and Facebook wont allow the url to be different from the page the user is.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You write Facebook wont allow urls which is different from the page. But this URL is valid and from the same domain. For example a Blog with multiple like button for each blog-entry on the same page (home-site). Is this really wrong?

Comment: Your question included a href value which was not a URL; if that token refers to a full URL you should clarify the question

Comment: facebook flags as it it using fbml